# htaccess - not working as expected

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to add some rewrite conditions to laravel's `public/.htaccess` file.

Here's the contents of the file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/page(.*)\.php$
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]*)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages%1/%2? [R=302,L]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Testing this online here ([link](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)), gives me the desired results which is `https://domain.com/page.php?id=1234 -> https://domain.com/pages/1234`

However, when I put it up on my server, I'm getting redirected to this url instead `https://domain.com/pages12345`.

It seems to me that the `(.*)` on this line `https://domain.com/campaign.php?id=12345` isn't being passed to `%1`. Instead only the query string value is being passed.

Is it possible it's because of a difference in apache versions? How might I amend this?

---

Also, can someone comment on the code itself? What I'm trying to do here is redirect any url that matches `/page*.php?id=1234` to `pages*/1234`.

ie.

```
/page.php?id=1234      -> /pages/1234
/page-home.php?id=1234 -> /pages-home/1234
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your rule to this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(page)([^.]*)\.php$ /$1s$2/%1? [R=302,NC,L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this.

**About regex:**

```
^       # input start
(page)  # match and group page in group #`
([^.]*) # match 0 or more of any char that is not a DOT and group it as group #2
\.php   # match literal .php
$       # end of input
```

**And replacement part:**

```
/   # literal /
$1  # backreference to group #1 i.e. (page)
s   # character s
$2  # backreference to group #1 i.e. ([^.]*)
/   # literal /
%1  # backreference to group #1 from RewriteCoond i.e. ([0-9]*)
?   # ? is used to strip off query string
```

Comment: @anubhave - This sort of works. adding an "s" to `/$1s/%1` satisfies the first part of what I'm trying to do. But the second part, it doesn't work. ie. `page-home?id=1234` is redirected to `page-homes/1234` instead of `pages-homes/1234`

Comment: try my updated rule again after clearing browser cache.

Comment: Alright. That works. Thanks. I'm still learning regex and it doesn't help that it's a little bit different for everything (php, js, command line, htaccess). Hehe. Thanks, again.

Comment: btw, if it's not too much to ask, can you maybe put in a small description of how this rewrite works, particularly the regex part. Thanks.

Comment: I have added explanation in my answer.